# Using tbl.Lookup to match just part of a column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, schematiq

This question relates to the Schematiq add-in for Microsoft Excel.

Using `=tbl.Lookup(table, columnsToSearch, valuesToFind, resultColumn, [defaultValue])` the values in the `valuesToFind` column have a consistent 3 characters to the left and then varying characters after (e.g. 908-123456 or 908-321654 - i.e. 908 is always consistent)

[image: table1]

How can I tell the function to lookup the value based on the first 3 characters only? The expected answer should be the sum of the results of the above, i.e. 500 + 300 = **800**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tbl.Lookup()` works by looking for an exact match - this helps ensure it's fast but in this case it means you need an extra step to calculate a column of lookup values, something like this:

```
A2: =tbl.CalculateColumn(A1, "code", "x => LEFT(x, 3)", "startOfCode")
```

This will give you a new column that you can use for the `columnsToSearch` argument, however `tbl.Lookup()` also looks for just one match - it doesn't know how to combine values together if there is more than one matching row in the table, so I think you also need one more step to group your table by the first 3 chars of the code, like this:

```
A3: =tbl.Group(A2, "startOfCode", "amount")
```

Because `tbl.Group()` adds values together by default, this will give you a table with a row for each distinct value of `startOfCode` and the subtotal of `amount` for each of those values. Finally, you can do the lookup exactly as you requested, which for your input table will return 800:

```
A4: =tbl.Lookup(A3, "startOfCode", "908", "amount")
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that makes sense. And it can all be combined into one long cell/formula too!